# How to click the login button for hackerrank with selenium and chromewebdriver?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I have tried all possibe ways to click a button by specifying it's xpath and also by creating my own, but it doesn't seem to work.
I've reffered to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47363513/xpath-for-text-login-and-the-login-button)

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome("/path_for_chromedriver_")
driver.get("https://www.hackerrank.com/login")

username = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="input-1"]')
username.send_keys('#MY EMAIL')

password = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="input-2"]')
password.send_keys('#MY PASSWORD')
```

could someone give me the code for finding and clicking this button with selenium

Comment: use `submit` method  instead of `click` . `driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".ui-btn-primary.auth-button").submit`

Answer (score 0):

Use the following `xpath` to click on **Log In** button.

> //button[.//span[text()='Log In']]

Code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome("/path_for_chromedriver_")
driver.get("https://www.hackerrank.com/login")

username = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="input-1"]')
username.send_keys('#MY EMAIL')

password = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="input-2"]')
password.send_keys('#MY PASSWORD')

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[.//span[text()='Log In']]").click()
```

---

Or Induce `WebDriverWait`() and `element_to_be_clickable`() and following `XPath`

```
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//button[.//span[text()='Log In']]"))).click()
```

You need to import following libraries.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```

Answer (score 0):

To send *character sequence* to the *Username* and *Password* field and `click()` on *Log In* button you can use either of the following  [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `css_selector`:

  ```
  driver.get("https://www.hackerrank.com/auth/login")
  WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"input.input[name='username']"))).send_keys("masterchief01")
  driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input.input[name='password']").send_keys("masterchief01")
  driver.find_element_by_css_selector("button[data-analytics='LoginPassword'] span.ui-text").click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  driver.get("https://www.hackerrank.com/auth/login")
  WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//input[@class='input' and @name='username']"))).send_keys("masterchief01")
  driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@class='input' and @name='password']").send_keys("masterchief01")
  driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@data-analytics='LoginPassword']//span[@class='ui-text']").click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```